# Three City Scheduling

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

I came across [the following interview question](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-city-scheduling/)

> There are 2N people a company is planning to interview. The cost of
>   flying the i-th person to city A is costs[i][0], and the cost of
>   flying the i-th person to city B is costs[i][1].
>
> Return the minimum cost to fly every person to a city such that
>   exactly N people arrive in each city.

The solution to this involves greedy approach, where we sort the array based on the "profit" parameter. profit of choosing city A for a candidate `i` is defined as `costs[i][1] - costs[i][0]` and choose the top half elements from the sorted array to go to A and rest to B.

**What if this question is modified to 3 cities and you have find optimal partition of n/3 chunks?** Will greedy algorithm still work?

Comment: Can i extend the greedy algorithm and modify the "profit" function to something like `Math.min(costs[i][1], costs[i][2]) - costs[i][0]`? Then assign the top n/3 candidates to city A. For the rest of the 2n/3, i can defer to the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalizing with $kn$ people and $k$ cities we can see "move to city $j$" as a task. Furthermore, we have $n$ copies of each task. For all copies of a task $j$, the cost for person $i$ to move to that task is $c_{i, j}$.

But now the problem is a direct instance of the [balanced assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), with complexity $O((kn)^3)$.

Comment: the problem definition in the wiki says that the sets should be of the same size. In our case, it is from N -> k .Is it the same problem ?

Comment: @Learner No, it's from $kn$ to $kn$. We have $kn$ people and $kn$ jobs (each job is copied $n$ times).